# Radio buttons in bootstrap material design become invisible while using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I use [bootstrap material design](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design)  to add material effects in my project, when I use `ng-repeat` with it the radio button become invisible, when I remove radio `radio-success` class radio button become visible but without its effect.

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="reason in questionData.reasons track by $index">
<div class="radio radio-success">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="currentquestion.correct_reason" value="{{$index}}" name="reason">
    {{reason}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure that framework provides `radio-success`?.. i don't that class in the core of the framework

Comment: yes I'm sure, but when I return to framework and I found another way to make radio button. 

from here 

http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#radio-button

I use this in bootstrap elements

http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I return to bootstrap material and I found another way to make radio button from bootstrap elements.

```
<div class="radio radio-primary"> 
    <label> 
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="">
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="check"></span> 
        Option one is this 
    </label> 
</div>
```